# How can I find out the very first time linux machine start up?

Tags: linux, uptime

When we use *uptime*, it only shown us the up-time of ours machine since it started from the last time it turning on/shutdown/reboot.

But, what if I want to get the time when our machine started from the very first time when it installed?

Do Linux own this tools? Or any clues about how I can find out the answer of it?

Comment: Which distribution? Some potential answers to this question may be distribution-specific.

Comment: @Michael: I'm using Debian server ...

Comment: You say "machine" but the answers seem to assume "installation". (Case in point, when I built my current PC and physically reinstalled the old hard disk with the old system still on it in the new case, the new machine essentially had an accumulated power-on time of 0 hours, but the installed system had been running for a long time already. Even this isn't completely accurate as I kept the same power supply that I had been using before...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're on a distribution that uses Anaconda, you can look at `/root/install.log`.

---

edit: It appears you're using Debian. [Debian places its install log](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch06s01.html.en) into /var/log/installer.

Comment: Thank you MDMarra ... using your answer and to find out the oldest file in it then I use command *ls -gt | tail -l* ...

Answer (score 21):

One of my favorite distribution-agnostic tricks is to check the [inode change time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31255/20805) of files or directories which are extremely unlikely to ever have been altered over the life of the server. These are generally directories in the root directory, such as `/lost+found`.

For example, this Ubuntu 10.04 LTS system was indeed installed around 9:40 pm on February 1, 2011.

```
# ls -lctr / | head -n 5
total 88
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-02-01 21:40 selinux
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-02-01 21:40 opt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-02-01 21:40 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-02-01 21:40 media
```

---

And finally, a sure fire answer which is reasonably sure to be accurate, if you have an ext* root filesystem. Look at the filesystem metadata, which contains the time the filesystem was created. For instance, this command shows the creation time for the filesystem mounted at `/`.

```
tune2fs -l $(grep " / " /proc/mounts | grep -v rootfs | cut -f 1 -d " ") | grep created
```

Comment: You are right Michael, it have the same value with timestamp of /var/log/installer, the answer that has answered by MdMara ... TYVM.